# How to display in a browser a video file that is not yet fully generated?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a program generating a video in some videofile and I would like this video file to be displayed in Firefox/Chrome/AnyOther, preferably in a HTML5 tag.

The problem is that if I start the HTML5 video while my video file is still only 5 seconds long, my browser will believe that the video actually is 5 second long, and will not display anything after t=5s.

How do I tell my browser that it shouldn't guess the duration of the video, and just read the file ?

I already have a solution involving a web server which would stream a video to the browser, but I am looking for a solution involving no server, if possible.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Maybe you can listen to an "end of video" event, get the current time and start the player again at this point in time.

Answer (score 0):

You should treat the video as if it is live, and use media source extensions rather that the video tag.